# How can I open an entry box ready to write on?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, tags, tkinter-entry

I use tkinter to open an entry box to add some tags to certain text I collect. Basically, when I copy the text, tkinter opens the entry box so I can insert my tags. The relevant part of the code is as follows (someone in this forum helped me out with it):

```
import tkinter

master = tkinter.Tk()
entry = tkinter.Entry(master)
entry.pack()
def close(event):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        string=entry.get()
        master.destroy()
    master.bind('<Key>', close)
    master.mainloop()
```

As the purpose of the code is to save AS MUCH time as possible, I would like that when the entry box pops up I don't have to manually go to the box with the mouse and click on it to start writting. I haven't found the way to do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Read about [Tkinter.Widget.focus-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus-method)

Comment: So you want to set the `focus()` on the entry box. `entry.focus()` after pack.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look... You guys being so helpful make us beginners lazy XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply `focus()` to `entry()` after you pack it.

You can also remove the need to check for `Enter` with the `keyboard` library by simply binding to `Return` instead of `Key`.

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
entry = yk.Entry(master)
entry.pack()
entry.focus()


def close(event):
    string = entry.get()
    master.destroy()


master.bind('<Return>', close)
master.mainloop()
```

Side note:

`focus()` and `focus_set()` are the exact same command. So either works. `focus()` is just an alias for `focus_set()`

Answer (score 1):

Just insert:
        entry.focus_set()

At the sixth line, just after entry.pack()